# BUSCAR PRODUCTOS POR CODIGO DE BARRAS

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando un sistame de control de ventas y de inventario con php y mysql,
en unas mejoras que estoy haciendo surgio la nesecidad de buscar los productos por su codigo de barras y generar un venta, mi problema es escaneo un codigo y me lista el producto, pero al leer un segundo codigo se me borra toda la informacion porque junta los dos codigo en el input, y no se como hacer que me lea n codigos que le paso con el lector de codigos sin perder el producto anterior y me liste todos los productos que leo y generar la venta.

```
este es mi ajax para enviar el codigo al php y funciona bien.

function buscar(cadena){
                
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'buscacodigo.php',
        data: 'cadena=' + cadena,
        success: function(respuesta) {
            //Copiamos el resultado en #mostrar
            $('#resultado1').html(respuesta);}});
    }

<?php 
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
         
            $query = "SELECT codigobarra,PRODUCTO FROM codigosbarra where codigobarra='$codigo'"; 
            $inven = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
            $row_venta = mysqli_fetch_array($inven);
            $totalRows_venta = mysqli_num_rows($inven); 
 
?>
  <table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="tablaprincipal">
        <td>Codigo de barra</td>
      <td>Producto</td>
    </tr>
 
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr class="brillo">
        <td align="center"3><?php echo $row_venta['codigobarra']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row_venta['PRODUCTO']; ?>&nbsp; </td>

      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_venta = mysqli_fetch_array($inven));?>
  </table>
```

este es mi select y muestro los registros, esto funciona bien, pero comente no logro hacer que me lea y busque mas con mas de un codigo

```
<input name="codigo[]" type="text" id="codigo" onkeypress="return valida(event);" onkeyup="buscar(this.value)"/>
```

recurro a su buena disposicion y tiempo
gracias

Comment: , Puedes hacerlo con jquery o js, limpiar o dar enter al momento de pistolear